# Evaluating probability mass function for a discrete random variable

Tags: distributions, self-study, random-variable

Consider the following pmf for a discrete random variable $X$: $f(x) = x/15$ when $x = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$, and $f(x)= 0$ for all other values of $x$. What is $f(3)$? (I.e., the PMF evaluated at 3)

Comment: This looks like homework - if it is could you add the "homework" tag and it will help people in giving a useful response.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is nicely contained within the question.  You need to look at the definition of $f(x)$.  $f(3)$ means "$f(x)$ evaluated when $x=3$".  So you can "plug in" the value of $x=3$ into the original definition to get an answer.